# Does anyone know the name of this specific part?

Tags: components, potentiometer

I bought these 10K linear faders some time ago and would like to use them in a current project. 
The only problem is that I don't know what they are so I can't order more / find the datasheet!

My suspicion is that they are bourns parts but I do not know the part number and the datasheets I found do not have any reference to the code on the bottom.

[image: Fader Top]

[image: Fader Bottom]

anyone able to fill me in?

Comment: Yes, this is a "linear potentiometer", or "slide potentiometers", but not necessary made by Bourns. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/potentiometers-variable-resistors/slide-potentiometers/78?k=potentiometer

Comment: Identifying a specific model number from a photo isn't really within the mission of this site.  Practically speaking, figure out what you *need* and go shopping for something meeting your needs which seems to have good availability in your quantities - something also not within the mission of this site.  A few minutes with an ohm meter and that ruler should let you determine minimum and maximum resistance and what sort of taper they have.

Comment: The prefix "B" indicates it is linear, and the rest says it's 10K.  There's nothing obvious to indicate the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that the resistance is definitely 10K.
I was just hoping perhaps someone might have seen this and recognised the code!
 Reason being that I don't have the money to buy more at this time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic linear taper slide potentiometer. You probably won't find a specific manufacturer or part number, unless you can match the 1630 to something. Instead you'll have to search for datasheets to find one of matching size.

The number B10K means B-taper 10kOhm, where B-taper indicates that the resistance changes linearly as you slide it. This is as opposed to logarithmic or audio tapers.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like a cheap clone](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11620).

Sparkfun has them.  [Datasheet](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/Switches/C-31-.pdf)